# Jade javascript block (Serverside)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am trying to write a few lines of server side javascript in the jade template engine.

I know for local scripts i can go

```
 script.
      as many lines as i want...
```

However i'm looking to do some server side stuff with something like

```
 -.
      many more lines...
```

Currently im stuck with

```
 -var i;
 -for(i = 1, i < 10; i++)
 -{
      -Do things...
 -}
```

So many dashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server-side in a Jade Template:

Instead of:

```
-    var i;
-    for(i = 1, i < 10; i++)
-    {
-         // Do things...
-    }
```

...do...

```
-
    var i;
    for(i = 1, i < 10; i++)
    {
         // Do things...
    }
```

You still use the hyphen '-' character, but you simply 'indent' your code. Everything 'indented' is treated as a block (just like normal Jade usage).

Answer (score 2):

Create a static `.js` file with the content like:

```
function do_things() {
  var i;
  for(i = 1, i < 10; i++)
  {
    Do things...
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
-do_things();
```

Comment: How do you import the .js file?

Comment: Also i probably forgot to mention I am not using node in this instance. I'm creating templates and i'm wondering if jade can run local .js during compilation to html.

Comment: In Jade: 
`script(src='path_to_script/dothings.js')`
-do_things()
Browser will load up the .js file just fine in the browser, you shouldn't need it compiled within jade

Comment: I'm trying to run code that shouldn't run in the browser and is simply interpreted by jade at compile time.